# Broadcast receiver in Titanium

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, titanium

I had tried to create a broadcast receiver in Titanium for my android application.

I found only Titanium docs for receiver, but this looks clumsy to me... [Link](https://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.BroadcastReceiver) 
. I couldn't find any tutorials to start receiver. Should i need to mention `<receiver>` in `Tiapp.xml`?

I had tried to call this in `app.js`, but no response:

```
var bc = Ti.Android.createBroadcastReceiver({
onReceived: function() {
    Ti.API.info('Handling broadcast.');
}
});

Ti.Android.registerBroadcastReceiver(bc, [Ti.Android.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED]);
```

I need to use when boot is completed.